# Arrow in Lightning-Accordion getting missed

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, slds, accordion

I have used `lightning-accordion` in an LWC component where the arrow mark is getting missed.
The below is present in the LWC documentation: [LWC Dcoumentation for lightning-accordion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-accordion/example)

This is the Accordion that is there in LWC documentation.

[image: LWC Diagram Accordion]

The HTML code shown in documentation is: [HTML Accordion doc](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/accordion/)

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_reset slds-accordion__summary-action" aria-controls="referenceId-45" aria-expanded="true" title="Accordion summary">
      <svg class="slds-accordion__summary-action-icon slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_left" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#switch"></use>
      </svg>
      <span class="slds-accordion__summary-content">Accordion summary</span>
</button>
```

The arrow is getting displayed by `<use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#switch"></use>`

But below is the HTML code in LWC component (I got from inspect (F12))
[image: Inspect]

And this is my accordion in LWC component:

[image: My LWC Accordion]

Why is the arrow mark missing in the accordion component? Can I get some help?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the [lightning-accordion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-accordion/example) component? That works with much less coding on your part.

Comment: I am using lightning-accordion only. My findings are from the inspect.

Comment: Ah OK. Suggest you post some of that code in your question. Or strip out everything in the `.html` and then build back up to see what exactly is causing the problem.

Comment: I guess you're using it from lightningdesignsystems, As @KeithC mentioned you can utilise accordion base component.